# Is it possible to generate struct from mapping in golang

Tags: go, struct, mapping

I have a mapping that changes dynamically with fields being added and removed, I was wondering if it was possible to create a struct like that

```
type Stats struct {
cnt      int
category map[string]Events
}
```

Without having to declare it beforehand. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "mapping that changes dynamically"? Can you give more details on the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Your question is unclear, but you can't create a type that isn't declared somewhere.

Comment: I was thinking to create a separate .go file that stores the last state of the created struct, and update this file if the received .json cannot be unmarshalled. This way the last known state can always be accessed without having to manually update the struct itself. I was thinking to do this by using the mapping of the newly received .json to update the struct. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: What are you doing with this proposed `.go` file? Compiling a new program and exec'ing into that? If you have dynamic keys you really just have to use a map.